# make ONLY ONE bootstrap header non-responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, header

There are quite a few posts here about changing the Bootstrap CSS to make the header non-responsive.

But I have two headers, only one of which I want to be non-responsive, so I don't want to change it as a class:

- One header has a login form, it works fine and collapses responsively exactly how I want it to.
- The other is for a logged-in user and only has one link to log out, and I want to make this non-responsive. Here's how it looks now as the browser width changes, which is obviously not ideal:

[image: Here's how it looks as the browser width changes]

And here's the code for the header I'd like to make non-responsive:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top identHeader8">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="dashboard.html">[logotype]</a>
    </div>

    <div id="logout_navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right collapse in">
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">Log out</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Non-nav Links (See [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-links)) and place it inside the header after the navbar-brand in this example.

```
<p class="navbar-text"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">Log In</a></p>
```

You can adjust to where is needed with your own CSS rules.

See example Snippet.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">[logotype]</a>

      <p class="navbar-text"><a href="#" class="navbar-link">Log In</a>

      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="index.html">Log out</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<img src="http://placehold.it/2050x850/ff0/fff" class="img-responsive">
```

Comment: Of course I had to adjust and tweak this code to match my case, but you gave me what I needed to get there. Thanks so much!